# Get the current List and Item from an application page accessed from a feature link

Tags: feature, application-pages

I've created a new feature for a specific list. This new feature will show a button in the EditToolBar of a list page when editing. After clicking that new button, it should take you to another page and display some data. I already added the xml files and also a .aspx files to the SharePoint folder and also installed the feature and activated it for that site.

Now, I can't get the current list and current item in my new aspx page by using SPContext.Current.List or SPContext.Current.Item. It gives an error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass through the List and Item IDs in the querystring?

The Context is lost in an application page I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, How can I do that from a feature? I mean, How can I get the values of this in the feature xml file.

Comment: How are you displaying the button in the toolbar in the first place?

Comment: Just by adding the line Location="EditFormToolbar" in the elements.xml of the feature.

Comment: Ah, understood, and you have a separate link which links to your application page in the elements.xml, also. I think the easiest way to be able to dynamically add stuff to the querystring is to use a usercontrol for the button on the toolbar.

Comment: I found that adding this to the element URL of the xml file 

?ItemId={ItemId}&amp;ListId={ListId} 

that information is added to the URL. Thanks James

Comment: Ah, good to know that, didn't realise that was possible!